# Loading a project file stops the script

Tags: pyqgis

I have a script, which should load a QGIS project and then show it's name. After the project should be loaded, nothing happens - but no error messages are shown. This script only says "Loading..". The script will terminate.

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject
project = QgsProject.instance()
print("Loading..")
project.read('C:\\Users\\Tambet\\Desktop\\Barcelona qgis\\planols1.qgs')
print(project.fileName())
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually debugged a bit more and found out the problem was in loading layers (map without layers loaded). Then I saw it was a possible duplicate of [PyQGIS Loading Project Layers not working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328524/pyqgis-loading-project-layers-not-working), because when I added the code from https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-standalone-scripts, it started to work - in the other question, also, the answer is correct path to qgis installation. I don't know, then, why in the manual they are importing from `qgis.core`, when this surrounding code loads * from there.